# Function for when an item becomes 'unstuck'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

This is probably simple, but so far have not been able to figure it out. I'm using Waypoints + Sticky for a header/logo area. I want the logo to have `preventDefault()` when it is stuck, so that clicks on it only do the `toggleClass()` action, but not follow the URL. But I need remove `preventDefault()` that when it is not stuck, so that clicking the logo will go to the website root URL as expected.

You can see it in progress here: http://radiantled.staging.wpengine.com

My script:

```
// Sticky Stuff
var header = $('#header');
var stuck_logo = $('.stuck #logo a');
var logo_shadow = $('.logo-shadow');
var header_height = header.outerHeight();
var header_offset = -(header_height+40);
var inner_header_height = inner_header.outerHeight();

header.waypoint('sticky',{
    offset: header_offset,
    handler: function() {
        stuck_logo.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            header.toggleClass('reveal');
            logo_shadow.toggleClass('hide');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you use:

```
$(document).on('click','.stuck #logo a', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   header.toggleClass('reveal');
   logo_shadow.toggleClass('hide');
});
```

and remove the function in handler

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks! Now to figure out why. :)

Comment: After reading [this article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html), which explains that `.on()` just passes through to `.bind()`, `.live()`, or `.delegate()`, depending on how it is used, I'm wondering if it might not be better to use `$(#header).on('click',...` since in that case `.on()` will use the `.delegate()` method, whereas if we use `$(document).on('click',...` `.on()` will use the `.live()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the article, its very helpful. I only prefer use  `.on()` because this dont need `$(document).ready` and I think my code is more ordered. I'm not sure if the performance difference is significant between delegate and live